# php array want to have value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

This is my php function

```
public function pointComplete() {

        $inputs = Input::all();

        print_r("<pre>");
        print_r($inputs);
        print_r("</pre>");
}
```

The output is the following:

```
Array
(
    [_token] => 2lIrWksIlJHjHASKAS0UDDSYLtcYwsDYCuxhjQ32
    [complete] => Complete
    [post_id_9] => 1
    [post_id_10] => 
    [post_id_12] => 2
    [post_id_13] => 
    [post_id_14] => 
)
```

I want to get this php array:

```
array (
    "post1" => array(
        "id" => "9",
        "point" => "1"
    ),
    "post2" => array(
        "id" => "12",
        "point" => "1"
    )
);
```

Comment: thats already in the array

Comment: But I want to input only post_id = 9, value = 1 and post_id = 12, value =2

Comment: sorry now one really knows what you are asking

Comment: @Dagon you read my mind...which is probably easier than figuring out this question...

Comment: So... you want remove the empty array's value? http://php.net/manual/it/function.array-filter.php Or what?

Comment: I want to be this array

'Array
(
    "post1"  => array (  
                                       "id" => "9",  
                                       "point" => "1",  
                                       ), 

"post2"  => array (  
                                       "id" => "12",  
                                       "point" => "1",  
                                       )

);'

Comment: manipulate `$inputs`? decide what from it to display? extract string\array - the possibilities are ...

Comment: It is an array...as you have it, it's an array.

Comment: ~tried to clarify your question~, see if I understand correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could go about this is to just loop through the input, and parse the key. Then put the result you parsed into another array.

```
$post_id = 1;
$posts = array();

foreach ($inputs as $key => $value) {
    $explode = explode('post_id_', $key);
    if (count($explode) == 2 && $value !== null) {
        $id = $explode[1];
        $posts['post'.$post_id] = array('id' => $id, 'value' => $value);
        $post_id++;
    }
}
```

[`print_r($posts)` will yield:](https://ideone.com/94gsxm)

```
Array
(
    [post1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [value] => 1
        )

    [post2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [value] => 2
        )

)
```

Although I am really just taking this question at face value here. There is probably a much easier way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: you could just explode on `post_id_` may be a little cleaner

Comment: @Dagon good idea. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: thanks @Zsw I want to be like that.

Comment: @nainglinhtut No problem. If the answer solved the problem for you, you could mark this answer as accepted.